# axWindowsMediaPlayer.currentMedia.duration won't update unless user action

Tags: c#, activex, wmp

I embedded Windows Media Player in a WinForms application and I need to retrieve the duration of the video, which is stored in axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration

The problem is that after I load a video the value will remain 0 until user action occurs. If I "break" the flow of the program with a MessageBox (or performing some other action on my UI), then the value of duration is set. Otherwise, it remains 0.

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Thanks

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Windows Media Player 12

Answer (score 0):

Loading a video doesn't mean that the duration will be set. Add a button named "Play" than - the duration must be set by clicking Play button.

If you share your codes here, I can test it.